# RTF in XSLT variable loses namespace URI in XSLTC TrAX

Tags: xslt, namespaces, xalan

When using the org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl XSLT transformer factory, the URI mapped to a prefix gets lost when the result tree is saved in a variable.

Consider the following namespace.xsl XSLT :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <xsl:template match="/node">
        <xsl:variable name="Var">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="body"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$Var" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="wrap" match="body">
        <xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')" />(<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')" />)[<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor-url')" />]</xsl:comment>
        <html>
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the following namespace.xml input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="namespace.xsl"?>

<node xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <html:h1 html:align="center">
            Hallo
        </html:h1>
    </body>
</node>
```

The result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--Apache Software Foundation (Xalan 
    XSLTC)(1.0)[http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j] -->
<html xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>

        <h1 xmlns:html="html" html:align="center">
            Hallo
        </h1>

    </body>
</html>
```

Please note the fact that **h1** has no prefix and inside the prefix **html** is assigned to the uri "**html**".

When I set the transformfactory to 'org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl' everything works as expected and I get the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--Apache Software Foundation(1.0)[http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j] -->
<html xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <html:h1 html:align="center">
            Hallo
        </html:h1>

    </body>
</html>
```

I can't find any known issues regarding this, does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

The following Java code is used to run the transformatin:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl");
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("namespace.xsl"));
transformer.transform(new StreamSource("namespace.xml"), new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("namespace_out.xml")));
```